# I have 2 flights by Ryanair. Funchal-Stansted and Stansted-Bologna. Do I need to do passport control in Stansted? Or I can stay airside?

Tags: uk, transit, ryanair, stn

I'm not sure if I can stay in transit or if I need to do passport control in Stansted.

I already did check in on line for both flights.

Comment: If you booked this as 2 separate tickets, then yes, you will have to clear Immigration, collect your bags and go back through security. Ryanair is a point-to-point airline, it offers a few connecting flights but AFAIK your itinerary isn’t one of them. See also https://www.stanstedairport.com/help/passenger-guides/connecting-flights/

Answer (score 10):

Ryan Air does not offer Funchal->Bologna as a single itinerary, so these are two separate tickets (which is typical for Ryan Air)

> I need to do passport control in London?

Yes. If you have bags checked, they will be unloaded in Stansted. You will have to collect them, go through customs and bring them to the Ryan Air bag drop to check them in again.

In some airports, you stay airside, if you have no checked bags and already have your boarding passes for the next flight. However, Stansted doesn't appear to be one of those. See
http://www.connectionreview.com/blog/connecting-at-london-stansted-airport-useful-tips-for-transit-passengers-40

Comment: So there isn't a connection flight inside. Also if i have only hand bag i need to go out and do control security again. Right?

Comment: Arriving internationally at Stansted, you must pass UK Immigration and Customs. It's easier if you don't have checked luggage. After you've done so, you must again pass through security to board your second flight.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it’s a disaster to queue to pass through passport control and then queue for hours to get back in.  I have photos of the cattle truck lines.  My advice... avoid transiting through Stansted like the PLAGUE.